# Incremental encrypted per database backup and Partial restore policy for MySQL 5.7 in replication setup

Tags: mysql, replication, backup, encryption, percona-tools

I will run a replication cluster using MySQL 5.7 and I would like to set up for each database a backup policy that has a full once per day + incremental every N hours with data encrypted (based on the full of the day). The backup will be done on the slave obviously.

I've looked to Percona xtrabackup documentation that cover [each](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.4/backup_scenarios/incremental_backup.html) [subject](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.4/backup_scenarios/encrypted_backup.html) apart but not together.

For the backup steps I do it this way

**Full backup command** once a day

```bash
xtrabackup --backup --encrypt=AES256 
  --encrypt-key="GCHFLrDFVx6UAsRb88uLVbAVWbK+Yzfs" \
  --compress
  --safe-slave-backup # in order to be able to restore on master \
  --slave-info \
  --databases foo
  --extra-lsndir=/data/backups/db_foo/20200201/full # to get clear text binlog info
  --target-dir=/data/backups/db_foo/20200201/full
```

**Incremental backup** every 2 hours

```bash
xtrabackup --backup --encrypt=AES256 
  --encrypt-key="GCHFLrDFVx6UAsRb88uLVbAVWbK+Yzfs" \
  --compress
  --safe-slave-backup # in order to be able to restore on master \
  --slave-info
  --databases foo
  --incremental-basedir=/data/backups/db_foo/20200201/full # use full directory of the day
  --extra-lsndir=/data/backups/db_foo/20200201/incr_020000
  --target-dir=/data/backups/db_foo/20200201/incr_020000
```

You can see for the backup I pass option `--extra-lsndir` to get the LSN / checkpoint info in clear text alongside the encrypted ones so the incremental backup can be done. From my test it seems to work fine.

**Layout of the full dump**

```
|/data/backups/db_foo/20200201/full 
├── backup-my.cnf.qp.xbcrypt
├── foo
│   ├── db.opt.qp.xbcrypt
│   ├── people.frm.qp.xbcrypt
│   └── people.ibd.qp.xbcrypt
├── ib_buffer_pool.qp.xbcrypt
├── ibdata1.qp.xbcrypt
├── xtrabackup_checkpoints
├── xtrabackup_checkpoints.xbcrypt
├── xtrabackup_info
├── xtrabackup_info.qp.xbcrypt
├── xtrabackup_logfile.qp.xbcrypt
└── xtrabackup_slave_info.qp.xbcrypt
```

However it's unclear to me the order of the steps necessary to restore the data with incremental and encrypted data together.

so my questions are:

- are the backup commands correct ?
- do you have some information how should I do the restoration? I'm confused about the order to run the decrypt/decompress/prepare, when to use `--apply-log-only` even after reading this [resource](https://fr.slideshare.net/MarceloAltmann/percona-xtrabackup-best-practices) and also how to restore only one database and not ALL the data.

Best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging a bit and also based on this [page](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.4/innobackupex/restoring_individual_tables_ibk.html) I have a solution that seems to work fine.

### Step 1: Decompress and decrypt backup files

```
xtrabackup --decompress --decrypt=AES256 --encrypt-key="GCHFLrDFVx6UAsRb88uLVbAVWbK+Yzfs" \ 
    --target-dir=/data/backups/db_xxx/full --remove-original
xtrabackup --decompress --decrypt=AES256 --encrypt-key="GCHFLrDFVx6UAsRb88uLVbAVWbK+Yzfs" \
    --target-dir=/data/backups/db_xxx/incr_1 --remove-original
xtrabackup --decompress --decrypt=AES256 --encrypt-key="GCHFLrDFVx6UAsRb88uLVbAVWbK+Yzfs" \
    --target-dir=/data/backups/db_xxx/incr_2 --remove-original
```

### Step 2: Prepare the data

- As we just want to restore one database and not the full mysql server data we pass `--export` to generate ready to copy files.
- We pass also `--apply-log` to all backup **except** the last one (from the docs I linked in the question)

```
xtrabackup --prepare --apply-log-only --target-dir=/data/backups/db_xxx/full/ --export
xtrabackup --prepare --apply-log-only --target-dir=/data/backups/db_xxx/full/ --incremental-dir=/data/backups/db_xxx/incr_1 --export
xtrabackup --prepare --target-dir=/data/backups/db_xxx/full/ --incremental-dir=/data/backups/db_xxx/incr_2 --export
```

### Step 3: Restore the data

Now we need to replace the table files without deleting the database.

```sql
mysql> SELECT CONCAT( 'ALTER TABLE ', a.TABLE_SCHEMA, '.' a.TABLE_NAME, ' DISCARD TABLESPACE;' ) AS 'DISCARD TABLESPACE'
    -> FROM information_schema.tables a WHERE a.TABLE_SCHEMA='foo';
+-----------------------------------------------+
| DISCARD TABLESPACE                            |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| ALTER TABLE foo.t1 DISCARD TABLESPACE;        |
| ALTER TABLE foo.t2 DISCARD TABLESPACE;        |
+-----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
cp -a /data/backups/db_xxx/full/foo/* /var/lib/mysql/foo/
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/foo/
```

```sql
mysql> SELECT CONCAT( 'ALTER TABLE ', a.TABLE_SCHEMA, '.' a.TABLE_NAME, ' IMPORT TABLESPACE;' )
    -> FROM information_schema.tables a WHERE a.TABLE_SCHEMA='foo';
+-----------------------------------------------+
| IMPORT TABLESPACE                             |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| ALTER TABLE foo.t1 IMPORT TABLESPACE;         |
| ALTER TABLE foo.t2 IMPORT TABLESPACE;         |
+-----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```